# Помогите с TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-tablayout

```
package com.example.aleks.example_tablayout;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TabLayout tabLayout = new TabLayout(this);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
    }
}
```

Почему программно не отображаются вкладки ? Когда делаю через разметку все нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Вы создали экземпляр табов, но не добавили его в разметку. Потому и не отображается. Вам надо добавить его программно в разметку экрана.